# Change the default data-theme from jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, image, cordova, offlineapps

With jQuery Mobile I can create a page using a custom theme

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="s" id="home">...
```

Now this works, but requires that I add this line in each of my pages and every-time I add a new page. I tried adding `data-theme="s"` to the body tag but this has no affect. Is there any way to do this other then setting it manually per page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to do it programmatically, AFAIK.

Something along the lines of:

```
$(document).bind( "mobileinit", function () 
{
    ...
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.contentTheme = "z"; //your theme
    ...
});
```

Now, since there is no centralized hook - you will have to do the similar line for all theme options there are:

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.headerTheme
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.footerTheme
```

and so on.

I don't have a list of all of them, but a quick look through the **jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.js** searching for `.prototype.options.` reveals these:

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnTheme
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.headerTheme
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.footerTheme
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.contentTheme
$.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterTheme
```

so it seems to me that you can go with these and discover more as you go. **Note** that not all of them are created like that - some are constructed dynamically in the code. Look for `Theme` string to see what I mean.

**Update**

`$.mobile.page.prototype.options.theme` should be updated as well - based on Moak's comment below.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will look into it and report back. This is a viable solution but it seems so silly that there wouldbn't be a method implemented for this.

Comment: along with `$.mobile.page.prototype.options.theme` this worked

Comment: In 1.4.0 (not sure of previous releases), you need to do this after you load jquery.js and BEFORE jquery.mobile*.js

Comment: Also in 1.4.0, it's sufficient to just set `$.mobile.page.prototype.options.theme`

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me. Just make sure it's called after JQM is initialized.

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.theme = "b";
```